# Infinite Java loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Please look at this code and tell me where I am making a mistake? I am new to java and I am getting an infinite loop on the below switch statement.

Below is the full method I am calling with system.out as placeholders until I fix the infinite loop.

Thanks in advance

```
public void startuserinterface()

{
    Scanner Menukeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    displaymainmenu();
    mainMenuChoice = Menukeyboard.nextInt();

    while(mainMenuChoice!=EXIT)
    {

        switch(mainMenuChoice){

        case DISPLAY_ROOMS :  {
            System.out.println(" I am displaying rooms ");

            break;
            }

        case DISPLAY_GUESTS : {
            System.out.println(" I am displaying guests  ");
            break;
        }

        case PROCESS_RESERVATION  : 
        {
            System.out.println(" I am displaying reserving ");
            displayreservationmenu();
            resMenuChoice = Menukeyboard.nextInt();
            runResMenu(resMenuChoice);
            break;
        }


        case PROCESS_PAYMENT : 
        {
            System.out.println(" I am payin  ");

            break;


        }

        }
    }

    System.out.println(" Goodbye ");
    displaymainmenu();



    }
```

Comment: You never change `mainMenuChoice`.

Comment: Why would I need to change mainmenuchoice if I have a break statement? It shouldn't continue looping with a break.

Comment: Because `break` breaks the `case`, not the `while` loop.

Comment: If the methods you call (namely, `displayreservationmenu()`, `enukeyboard.nextInt()`, and `runResMenu()`)  don't affect the `mainMenuChoice`, it will never get the value of `EXIT`, so the while loop will never end.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the feedback. I have updated the method the while loop is driven by user input.

Comment: @MarkyF `the while loop is driven by user input` - No, it isn't. You get the user input only once *before* the while, you never get it again inside the `while` loop and you never update `mainMenuChoice`.

Answer (score 1):

After switch statement is done and break occurs, the condition goes back to while loop. And it again checks the same value i.e does not equal to Exit and hence it again runs the switch statement.

Basically you are checking again and again on same Exit without changing the value. And since on first attempt the value was not equals to Exit which makes it true every time while is checked, so it will run forever.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know where I went wrong. amateur error no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end while loop. In given example break; only ends switch statement and while loop is executed again. And because there was no place to change the while loop condition, it means that this loop will be always true -> will be executed forever.